# Enable android:forceDarkMode programmatically?

Tags: android, android-10.0

Android Q introduced a setting to force dark mode on apps without worrying about changing the colors manually: https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme#force_dark

This works fine even for my app which uses a WebView! However, I would like to give users the choice to enable dark mode whenever they need it. Is it possible to leverage the automatic changes done by "android:forceDarkAllowed" for that purpose?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can programmatically [enable the dark theme on Android Q](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme#changing_themes_in-app) with the following code:
`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`

Comment: While this toggles your app to a dark theme, it is not the same as "the automatic changes done by `android:forceDarkMode`". `android:forceDarkMode` is a system capability and is not tied to AppCompat.

Comment: Are you sure? In my testing it did everything I expected it to do (e.g. change background color of WebView too) when used on Android Q. Older versions of Android did not behave the same of course.

Comment: Well, I could have `android:forceDarkMode="true"` on an app that does not use AppCompat. Tracing through the code behind `setDefaultNightMode()` leads me to [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/32a7dec0a0f39707d14341ba507b48ef2eb3f1fe/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java#L2217-L2317), which I can't completely grok. I suppose it's possible that `forceDarkMode` is doing at the system level what this code is doing at the `ContextThemeWrapper` level.

Comment: Ok good point, I should mention that I do use one of the AppCompat-provided themes which might be the reason why it works for me.

Comment: Your answer is the most likely solution for most developers; I'm just being a bit pedantic.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, I guess that is kind of your job as the Android hero of StackOverflow. Thanks for all your work!